# AccessViolation with TThread.Synchronize and DLLs

Tags: delphi, dll, synchronize, tthread

I'm using the WorkerThread from DelphiPraxis with Delphi XE2.
http://www.delphipraxis.net/93835-workerthread-der-diener-im-hintergrund.html
In my JobThread, I'm loading a DLL, which does some waiting (for Testing..)

```
function DLLClass.doStuff(): boolean;
var
  I: integer;
begin
  try
    for I := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      sleep(10);
      if (assigned(StatusCallback)) then
        StatusCallback(PWideChar(I));
    end;
    Result := true;
  except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      error := 'DLL FEHLER: ' + e.ClassName + ' - ' + e.Message;
      Result := false;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The "StatusCallback" is a Reference to a procedure in the Thread whichis loading the DLL:

```
  TStatusUpdate = procedure(Status: PWideChar) of object; stdcall;
```

My Callback looks like this:

```
procedure JobThread.statuscall(status: pwidechar); stdcall;
begin
  //saving the Status in a global Variable..
  if Assigned(OnStatus) then
    fThread.Synchronize(syncStatus);
end;
```

Which calls:

```
procedure JobThread.syncStatus;
begin
  if Assigned(OnStatus) then
  begin
    OnStatus(self);
  end;
end; //<- AV here!
```

OnStatus eventhandler:

```
Procedure TfMain.uploadStatus(aJob: TWorkerThreadJob);
begin
  //doing nothing.. yet an AV
  sleep(10);
end;
```

I think the problem is somehow related to the DLL not being able to Synchronize with the MainThread. 
Any ideas on working around the Synchronize (if it's actually the problem)?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you're getting in the AV? "I get an access violation" is pretty meaningless unless you give us information about the error itself. It also helps if you provide some information about where the AV is happening - "Here are several chunks of code out of context. Somewhere I'm getting an access violation" also is pretty vague.

Comment: The exact errormessage is:
'access violation at 0x0047ff9e: write of address 0x00000020'

The AV is marked in in the fourth* code-block. Since the Debugger is stopping on the "end;", I think the problem is somewhere else.

`TThread.Synchronize:
0047FF98 55               push ebp
0047FF99 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
0047FF9B 53               push ebx
0047FF9C 8BD8             mov ebx,eax
0047FF9E 895B20           mov [ebx+$20],ebx //Error's here`

Comment: The low memory address at the `write` is suspicious; it's usually a sign of accessing something that hasn't been created (or has been freed). The more suspect thing, though, is the second code block's comment regarding a "global variable", which is absolutely, positively a bad thing when threads are involved.

Comment: "global" but still in the TThread class. Also, no difference if i comment that part out.

I'm really confused about the write too, since I'm not writing or reading anything in the synchronized part. That's why I thought of an issue regarding DLLs and Synchronize.
Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Build your test with debug dcu's enabled, so that you will be able to set breakpoints in VCL sources (ex in `Synchronize`) and find out the exact line that causes AV.

Comment: Are you loading functions from the DLL? Are you 100% sure the function sigs match on both sides of the module boundary?

Comment: The "DLLClass" is instantiated (from the DLL) and used.